# Change color of specific words in sublime text 3

Tags: php, colors, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I search on this site how to change color of some specific words in Sublime Text 3, but cannot find it without replacing the tmlanguage file.

What I'ld like is to change color for `true` (make it green) and `false` (make it red) or things like the `$this`.

I'm specially interested for PHP and JS scope, as I don't really use any other language. I tried [PersistentRegexHighlight](https://github.com/skuroda/PersistentRegexHighlight) plugin, but I'm not quite satisfy with the result. The words are not colored on file opening, and it uses highlight, so I cannot just change text color.

I read some answers about changing the PHP.tmlanguage file, but doing that, I'll loose any change in future versions, right? I thought making another PHP.tmlanguage in the user dir will 'add it' to the main one, like keybinding file, but no.

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your own `PHP.tmlanguage` in User directory is not working because editing a `.tmlanguage` file is a way to describe language and set up scopes, not a way to highlight terms. So you need additional actions in order to highlight those things in the editor window.

Highlighting is done in `.tmTheme` file. In the file, you can use scopes from `.tmLanguage` in order to apply color for the text suitable for the scope.

### 1. PHP.tmLanguage

As I know, maybe I wrong, it's not possible to create a "patch" file for syntax definition. You can't create a little patch file which will extend PHP syntax. The syntax is described in one file, so all scopes for PHP must be described in one file. If you want to add, delete, or change something for PHP language, you need to edit appropriate file, which must contain syntax definition for the whole PHP. Good thing is, it is possible to copy `.tmLanguage` file to the `User` directory and keep native file safe.

Let's copy `PHP.tmLanguage` in your `User` folder and edit it a bit. You can find those strings inside:

```
<dict>
    <key>match</key>
    <string>(?i)\b(TRUE|FALSE|NULL|__(FILE|DIR|FUNCTION|CLASS|METHOD|LINE|NAMESPACE)__|ON|OFF|YES|NO|NL|BR|TAB)\b</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>constant.language.php</string>
</dict>
```

As you can see, right now both `true` and `false` are inside the same scope, `constant.language.php`. You can change it by removing them from the scope and adding two separate scopes for them.

```
<dict>
    <key>match</key>
    <string>(?i)\b(NULL|__(FILE|DIR|FUNCTION|CLASS|METHOD|LINE|NAMESPACE)__|ON|OFF|YES|NO|NL|BR|TAB)\b</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>constant.language.php</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>match</key>
    <string>(?i)\b(TRUE)\b</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>true.constant.language.php</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>match</key>
    <string>(?i)\b(FALSE)\b</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>false.constant.language.php</string>
</dict>
```

### 2. Theme modification

It's not possible to setup colors in `tmLanguage` file because its purpose is determine scopes — language elements. All syntax highlighting done in `.tmTheme` files. So best thing I can imagine is copying current theme file to the `User` directory and edit it.

For example, if your current theme is `Slush & Poppies`, you would copy it from `ST3/Packages/Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package\Slush & Poppies.tmTheme` to the `ST3/User/Data/Packages/User` dir and edit.

Search for the string, `constant.language`. It is part of this block:

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Built-in constant</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>constant.language</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict/>
</dict>
```

Looks like `Slush & Poppies` has no settings for coloring constants. But it's not a problem. In the code below I've written a sample which helps understand how to apply color settings. So, let's change above block to this one:

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Built-in constant</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>constant.language</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict/>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>TRUE</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>true.constant.language</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#008900</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>FALSE</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>false.constant.language</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#890000</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Restart ST3 (looks like ST3 do not completely update scopes list from changing `.tmLanguage` file during runtime, so better restart it) and select menu "Preferences" → "Color Scheme" → "User" → "Slush & Poppies". In this theme you will have `true` highlighted with green and `false` highlighted with red. Of course, you can edit any color scheme you want, not only this one.

One more thing, in `.tmTheme` file you can use not the whole scope name, but its part. For example, it's possible to use `false.constant.language` instead of `false.constant.language.php`. When you use `false.constant.language`, the settings will be applied to all scopes whose name is started from `false.constant.language`. For example, if you have defined `false.constant.language.php` in PHP.tmLanguage and `false.constant.language.js` in JavaScript.tmLanguage, you can use `false.constant.language` in `.tmTheme` file and its setting will be applied both to JS and PHP `false`.

Comment: Thank you for this amazing answer! It worked very well. Even if the solution has one major default, the user/PHP..tmLanguage will override any ST PHP.tmLanguage future update, so I'll have to monitor any improvement, but fortunately, it's not so often.

Comment: Usually I like to invent something. Sorry, right now I can't provide better recipe for your case, but I will add your question in my favorites, and will try to invent something better in near future. ))))

Comment: @SergeyRonin Voted you past 1000 Reputation! (Also a very detailed and useful answer)

Comment: @Druzion Thanks you. :)

Comment: Great, this comment helped me to know how to modify constant.numeric color. Thanks